# Laravel routes and pretty urls doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes, pretty-urls

I'm new in Laravel. I develop a project on my local computer and it works properly. But when I publish it to the server, I just can see the main page and pretty URLs (contain CSS files and all other directories) and Laravel routes doesn't work.

Here is my configurations:

```
debeian 8
apache

PHP 5.6.24-0+deb8u1
```

`.htaccess` content on `laravel/public`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: when you enter a route which is the error displayed?

Comment: its replying not found: Not Found

The requested URL /contact was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 91.109.23.205 Port 80